# A square can't be divided into 2, 3 or 5 smaller squares

Tags: geometry

I have just read that a square can't be divided into 2, 3 or 5 smaller squares (not necessarily distinct). I am unable to think of a way to prove it. Can anyone help me by providing a hint?

Comment: What does "not necessarily distinct" mean? Distinct sizes?

Comment: Smaller squares may or may not have same area.

Comment: I have found a related thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337337/divide-a-square-into-different-parts?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n<4$, at least one of the squares must cover two vertices of the original square. These vertices must also be vertices of the smaller square and it must not protrude; we conclude that it has side length $\ge 1$ and covers the big square by itself.

For $n=5$, there must be exactly one small square that does *not* cover a vertex of the original square. Only few configurations of neighbourship are possible, and none of the works.

Comment: Aha , extremal principle in action. Thanks for the wonderful proof.

Answer (score -1):

When a square gets divided in to more squares there are (divisions)*(divisions) new squares. If you divide a square two times you get 4 squares.

Comment: I have just arrived at this conclusion for n=2. But what about 3 and 5?

Comment: why is this true for square and not triangle?

Comment: @Arjang for triangle one can draw a perpendicular to opposite side and divide it into two different triangle.

Comment: But you *can* divide a square into 6 squares. Also in 11 squares, and lots of other numbers.

Comment: How would you divide a square in 6 squares?

Comment: @Arjihad three of side length $\frac 13$ on top, two more on the right, another of side length $\frac23$ for the rest

Comment: @GerryMyerson Except n=2 , 3 and 5 a square can be sub divided into other squares for any other n. See a related thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337337/divide-a-square-into-different-parts?rq=1