# An equilateral triangle can't be divided into 2, 3, or 5 equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to prove an equilateral triangle can't be divided into 2, 3, or 5 smaller equilateral triangles, with no gaps nor overlaps, and not counting triangles with segments running through? Similar to this question:
[A square can't be divided into 2, 3 or 5 smaller squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1688313/723086)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would say that it's impossible based on the fact that, by definition, all equilateral triangles are similar. Any cevian drawn in an equilateral triangle will necessarily split the angle at the vertex it's drawn from into two angles not equal to 60 degrees, and thus the triangles it forms cannot be equilateral. This situation cannot be rectified by drawing more cevians. If you're willing to consider arbitrary line segments however then it is possible: any line segment drawn inside the triangle parallel to one of its sides will form a smaller equilateral triangle inside the original one.

Comment: (Continued) you can draw as many of these lines as you like; however, all of the new triangles will be "nested" inside the original one, which I wouldn't exactly consider "splitting" it

Comment: @H.sapiensrex If you make this an answer, can you explain why at least one cevian must be drawn on the original triangle, or how this fact of cevians splitting angles comes into play? It feels like your comment is very nearly a proof/answer, but it's just a bit too terse.

Comment: [Possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337337/divide-a-square-into-different-parts?rq=1) [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688313/a-square-cant-be-divided-into-2-3-or-5-smaller-squares)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note firstly that every line segment must be parallel to a side. Otherwise there must be an angle that is not 60°. This can be proved by induction on the number of segments. This also guarantees that every triangle bounded by these line segments will be equilateral.

Call the triangle ABC. To cover the triangle there must be an equilateral triangle in corner A, and as the remaining shape is not a triangle we can't cover ABC with two triangles. Similarly there must be a different triangle in each corner, and as they don't overlap you have a remaining shape, so we can't cover ABC with three triangles.

With a triangle in each corner the remaining shape can be a triangle, a quadrilateral, a pentagon or a hexagon. If it is a triangle the shape is covered with  four (equilateral) triangles. If it is a quadrilateral, a pentagon or a hexagon it has two adjacent 120° angles. Each of these angles contains two triangles, and they cannot be the same two triangles. It follows that this shape contains at least three triangles, and combined with the triangles at each corner there is a total of at least six triangles. This means we cannot cover ABC with exactly five triangles.

Note that if the long side of a 60° isosceles trapezium is an integral multiple (say $n$) of its diagonal sides, it can be split into $2n-1$ equilateral triangles. If we cut off such a trapezium with long side BC we can split ABC into 4, 6, 8, ... triangles. If we also divide the triangle at A into 4 triangles we can split ABC into 7, 9, 11, ... triangles. In other words we can split ABC into any number of triangles except 2, 3, or 5.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Follow what Hagen did in his solution to the linked problem.

Show the following. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

1. If a triangle is divided into 2, then the new vertex that is introduced must be on the perimeter.
2. If the new vertex is introduced on the perimeter, then there are 3 equilateral triangles at that point.
3. Hence, an equilateral triangle cannot be divided into 2 equilateral triangles.
4. If a triangle is divided into 3, then either we have a new vertex in the interior, or 2 new vertices on the perimeter.
5. If a new point is introduced in the interior, then there are 4 or 6 equilateral triangles at that point.
6. Hence, an equilateral triangle cannot be divided into 3 equilateral triangles.
7. If a triangle is divided into 5, then what can we say?

   - We cannot have an interior point that is the vertex of 6 equilateral triangles. So any interior point is the edge of a triangle meeting 3 vertices, and contributes $180^\circ$ to the angle sum.
   - Any such interior point connects to 2 perimeter points. (If it doesn't extend out to the perimeter, show that we have a lot of triangles.)
   - Any point on the perimeter (that is not the vertex) contributes $180^\circ$ to the angle sum.
   - If we have 2 points on the perimeter of a side, then that gives us 5 equilateral angles which do not include the other vertex, so we have at most 1 perimeter point on each side.
   - Hence, we have $n \leq 3$ points on the perimeter, and $4-n$ points in the interior.
   - For $n = 3$, each side has a perimeter point, which gives us the 4 equilaterial triangle case only.
   - For $n = 2$, the 2 interior points map to the same/only 2 perimeter points, hence all of these lie on a line. This leaves us an isosceles trapezium, which is not an equilateral triangle.
   - For $n = 0, 1$, any interior point maps to 2 perimeter points, hence a contradiction.
8. Hence, an equilateral triangle cannot be divided into 5 equilateral triangles.

Note: Show further that

- For $n = 4$, we can split an equilateral triangle into $n$ equilateral triangles.
- For $n \geq 6$, we can split the equilateral triangle into $n$ equilateral triangles.

  - Hint: It might be easier to split into the odd and even case.
- Hence, we can split iff $n = 1, 4, \geq 6$.
- Note the similarities with the [square case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337337/divide-a-square-into-different-parts?rq=1)

Comment: For n = 5 there must be one equilateral triangle at each vertex. If they all have the same size, there's an equilateral triangle in the middle, which we know can't be split into 2, as already established. If they don't all have the same size, there's a convex 5-gon in the middle, which can't be partitioned into 2 triangles. Does that work?

Comment: Oh it can be a hexagon too. My mistake.

Comment: @PuzzleAndy There could be several ways to approach it. I found it easier to create a rigorous argument by looking at the side/interior points.

Comment: If you'd like to share your reasoning for n = 5, I'm all ears.

Comment: @PuzzleAndy I take that back. Peter has a much better/cleaner argument than my train of thought. $\quad$ I edited my reasoning in.